# regex Processing IDE( Java) from HTML string

Tags: java, html, processing

so lets give a little background. I am attempting to grab a dynamic value from a webpage (web crawling), that I will be able to apply conditionals too it once ive parsed/received it.

Here is the page reference: http://www.nba.com/gameline/heat/

I am trying to grab the amount of "wins" variable for the team in the chart, and then apply conditionals. I've successfully loaded the content of the page in my sketch, but am receiving a `PatternSyntaxException`  error due to my limited scope of understanding how to write regular expressions.

Code below:

```
String webpage = "";
String [] webpageArray = loadStrings("http://www.nba.com/gameline/heat/");


for(int i=0;i<webpageArray.length;i++){
  webpage += webpageArray[i];
}



webpage = webpage.replace("  "," ");
webpage = webpage.replace(" ","");

println(webpage);

//String[] m1 = match(webpage, "<div id=\"article\">(.*)</div></div>");

String[][] m1 = matchAll(webpage, "(?<=nbaTmOverStats.*?nbaTeamFG4\">)\\d+");

//String[] m1 = match(webpage, "NAKED (.*) - just two");

//println(webpage);
//println(m1[1]);

size(640,480);
background(255);
fill(0);

//String s = m1[1];
//text(s, 15, 20, width, height);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
<div id=.nbaTmOverStats.*id=.nbaTeamFG4.>(\\d+)</td>
```

This will extract the number value of the field with id="nbaTeamFG4".
Since matchAll is a method corresponding to [Processing 2.0+](http://www.processing.org/reference/matchAll_.html), getting the data out looks like this

```
    String m1[][] = matchAll(webpage, "<div id=.nbaTmOverStats.*id=.nbaTeamFG4.>(\\d+)</td>");
    //Print the first match
    println(m1[0][1])'
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I attempted both of your suggested methods as follows:   String[][] m1 = matchAll(webpage, "nbaTmOverStats.*nbaTeamFG4\\">(?<stats>\\d+)");
 but starting from the point of the first part >(?<stats>//d+)... is not contained in brackets. "Unterminated string constant"

Comment: Sorry, I made an error in my regex. I've updated my answer and tested this one successfully.

Comment: i've tested and still get a PatternSyntaxError. I've also tested the other method (i imported: import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*; ) but still receive the same error.  here is my revised line:   String[][] m1 = matchAll(webpage, "(<div id=\"nbaTmOverStats.*id=\"nbaTeamFG4\">)(?<stats>\\d+)");

Comment: Can you post your matchAll method?

Comment: ha! no problem! really appreciate all your help thus far

Comment: <div id=.nbaTmOverStats.*id=.nbaTeamFG4.>(\\d+)</td> Try that. I can't test this as I don't have that library installed. Also if you want the team name out too, you will need another group. I'm not sure which field corresponds to the team name.

Comment: Perfect! compiles fine. I seem to be getting a nullpointerexception from my print message to see the variable (wins) with println(m1[1]);

Comment: Ah that's eaiser. It's a double array so you need two brackets. m1[0][1] should get the first match

Comment: Great! I'd buy you a beverage of choice if I could. Cheers!